# Python module bqplot_extra

Tags: python-3.x, pypi, bqplot

I'm trying to follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i40d8-Hu4vM) presentation from `Jupytercom`, but the package `bqplot_extra` seems not available for installation.

```
ModuleNotFoundError      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2c57530162d2> in <module>()
      2 
      3 from bqplot import LinearScale, Scatter, Figure
----> 4 from bqplot_extra.regression_lines import *

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bqplot_extra'
```

**jupyter notebook error:**

[image]

Where could I find this package?
Is not available in `bqplot` core libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can't because it uses some proprietary Bloomberg code. See https://github.com/bloomberg/bqplot/issues/569